# Unable to get jest to load a module (pdf.js) in a component test

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pdf.js

I am building tests using jest that makes use of the pdf.js node library, but keep getting the following error due to jest not picking up the library properly

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'workerSrc' of undefined
```

Here is `pdfParser.js`:

```
import * as pdfJs from 'pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf'

import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'

pdfJs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker

export const readPdf = async theFile => {
 ... (*it doesn't even get this far)
}
```

Here is my test (`pdfParser.test.js`):

```
import { readPdf } from '../../../../src/utils/pdfParser.js'

describe('PDF Parser', () => {
  it('returns error when no file submitted', () => {
    expect(1).toEqual(1)
  })
})
```

I've tried setting the following in `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "pdfjs-dist": "<rootDir>/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      ".",
      "src",
      "src/util",
      "node_modules"      
    ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: Importing `pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf` should have done the trick.. Have you tried to NOT set `workerSrc`? I also didn't need to change Jest configs. Maybe also remove `node_modules` and run `npm ci` again